# Right SQL statement to get the late and OT of employees

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my sql query as of the moment:

```
select Employee_Number, Cast([DateTime] as Date) as 'DateTime', MIN([DateTime]) as 'MIN', MAX([DateTime]) as 'MAX' , [Hours Worked] =
CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR ,min([DateTime]), max([DateTime])) / 24) AS VARCHAR) +
' Days ' +
CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR , min([DateTime]),  max([DateTime])) % 24) AS VARCHAR) +
' Hours ' +
CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min([DateTime]), max([DateTime])) % 60) AS VARCHAR) +
' Minutes ' +
CAST((DATEDIFF(SECOND, min([DateTime]), max([DateTime])) % 60) AS VARCHAR) +
' Seconds '  , [Over Time] = CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR, '17:30:00:000', MAX([DateTime])) % 24) AS VARCHAR) + ' Hours ' + 
CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '17:30:00:000', max([DateTime])) % 60) AS VARCHAR) + ' Minutes', [LATE] = 
CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR, '08:30:00:000',Min([DATETIME])) % 24) AS VARCHAR) + ' Hours ' + CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '08:30:00:000', MIN([DateTime])) % 60) AS VARCHAR) + ' Minutes'
from tblExtract group by Employee_Number, Cast([DateTime] as Date)
```

And this is what this query shows:

The problem arose if the employee entered early before 8:30 and if he leaves early as well before 17:30
[image]

How can I correct this? How Can I get a Case where if the Employee leaves or arrive early the LATE or Overtime Column would have a value of '0 hours 0 minutes'?

Comment: What do you expect to get in those cases?

Comment: @Szymon to get a default value like 0 hours 0 minutes. If he arrives and leave early.

Comment: Ok, please update your question with that information. All the important information should be in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display `'0 Hours 0 Minutes'` if a person arrives/leaves early, you can use `CASE` for that.

```
select Employee_Number, Cast([DateTime] as Date) as 'DateTime', MIN([DateTime]) as 'MIN', MAX([DateTime]) as 'MAX' , [Hours Worked] =
    CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR ,min([DateTime]), max([DateTime])) / 24) AS VARCHAR) +
    ' Days ' +
    CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR , min([DateTime]),  max([DateTime])) % 24) AS VARCHAR) +
    ' Hours ' +
    CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min([DateTime]), max([DateTime])) % 60) AS VARCHAR) +
    ' Minutes ' +
    CAST((DATEDIFF(SECOND, min([DateTime]), max([DateTime])) % 60) AS VARCHAR) +
    ' Seconds '  , [Over Time] = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '17:30:00:000', CONVERT(TIME, MAX([DateTime]))) < 0
    THEN '0 Hours 0 Minutes'
    ELSE
        CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR, '17:30:00:000', MAX([DateTime])) % 24) AS VARCHAR) + ' Hours ' + 
        CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '17:30:00:000', max([DateTime])) % 60) AS VARCHAR) + ' Minutes'
    END, 
[LATE] = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '08:30:00:000', CONVERT(TIME, MIN([DateTime]))) < 0
    THEN '0 Hours 0 Minutes'
    ELSE
        CAST((DATEDIFF(HOUR, '08:30:00:000',Min([DATETIME])) % 24) AS VARCHAR) + 
        ' Hours ' + CAST((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '08:30:00:000', MIN([DateTime])) % 60) AS VARCHAR) + ' Minutes'
    END

from Extraction
group by Employee_Number, Cast([DateTime] as Date)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8847/3)

Comment: The query still produce the same results.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8847/1 Here it is sir the query that you gave to me. I've changed some values

Comment: @LucasJuan You're right. I had to also convert to `TIME` to get rid of the date part for comparison. Please see my update.